# Initializer type "express".e is not assignable to variable type exports

Tags: node.js, express, typescript

This is the error I get on var express = require("express");

```
Initializer type "express".e is not assignable to variable type exports
```

in my NodeJS + Express project that I'm trying to convert to typescript. I got the NodeJS and ExpressJS .d.ts files from here:

https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped

Not sure what this error means, and how to fix it. My "application.ts" file which is where I am trying to write my app.js in Typescript does not recognize any ExpressJS functions, even through they reference a common header file that references back to both of them.

Is there any way in which the references I have placed might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should import express into typescript as follows:

```
import express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

Always a good idea to look at the tests for a definition file
https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/express/express-tests.ts#L3-L4

Comment: The catch is that this prevents you from organising your code in a sane, C# style way (class/interface per file). You are now forced to shove entire namespaces into one file each. This is because you can't import external modules from internal modules. This is an impediment to "application scale" development, contrary to the claim made on the TypeScript homepage.

Comment: It claims to application scale JavaScript. If you need JavaScript, use Typescript. That claim holds

Comment: Not sure I'm following you. My understanding of the claim "application scale JavaScript development" is that TypeScript enables us to build bigger, more complex software than with JavaScript. Indeed it does this to some extent with its type checking, but not to the dramatic extent it could improve codebase scalability had it included a way to organize large codebases.